# How to convert HTML Div contents to application/pdf mimetype base64 string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I Created an HTML page to show the invoice, now I would need the Base64 string of DIV content as application/pdf mimetype.

Currently I'm using **btoa** to encode the div content, which is converting to base64 text/html mimetype, but I need the Base64 string in application/pdf mimetype.